# Varnish+nginx and gzipped svg

Tags: nginx, varnish

I need some help understanding what exactly is going on in this scenario.
I cannot for the life of me serve this svg file though varnish.

My setup is NGINX on port 8080 as a backend for Varnish on port 80. Very simple. All works fine except for this SVG file. Note that I can serve other SVG files just fine! But looking at the file markup it seems pretty much the same as others. Serving though nginx it renders nice.

Check this line - Gunzip error: -3 (incorrect header check)

Whole varnishlog above.

```
*   << BeReq    >> 458807
-   Begin          bereq 458806 fetch
-   Timestamp      Start: 1476832525.282152 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /images/logo-fibersals.svg
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    Host: fibersals.com.br
-   BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
-   BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 179.177.210.249, 179.177.210.249
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 458807
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   BackendOpen    29 boot.default 127.0.0.1 8080 127.0.0.1 43215
-   BackendStart   127.0.0.1 8080
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1476832525.282200 0.000048 0.000048
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1476832525.283278 0.001127 0.001079
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   200
-   BerespReason   OK
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: image/svg+xml
-   BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
-   BerespHeader   Server: nginx
-   BerespHeader   Last-Modified: Tue, 18 Oct 2016 21:34:00 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   BerespHeader   ETag: "58069548-24f6"
-   BerespHeader   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   BerespHeader   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   BerespHeader   Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   BerespHeader   Date: Tue, 18 Oct 2016 21:34:15 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
-   BerespHeader   X-Original-Content-Length: 9462
-   BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
-   BerespHeader   Content-Length: 3684
-   BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   BerespHeader   ETag: "58069548-24f6"
-   BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
-   BerespHeader   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   BerespHeader   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   BerespHeader   Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   TTL            RFC 315360000 10 -1 1476832525 1476832525 1476826455 2145916555 315360000
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
-   TTL            VCL 315360000 259200 0 1476832525
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Storage        malloc s0
-   ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ObjStatus      200
-   ObjReason      OK
-   ObjHeader      Content-Type: image/svg+xml
-   ObjHeader      Server: nginx
-   ObjHeader      Last-Modified: Tue, 18 Oct 2016 21:34:00 GMT
-   ObjHeader      Vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding
-   ObjHeader      ETag: "58069548-24f6"
-   ObjHeader      X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   ObjHeader      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   ObjHeader      X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   ObjHeader      Date: Tue, 18 Oct 2016 21:34:15 GMT
-   ObjHeader      Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
-   ObjHeader      X-Original-Content-Length: 9462
-   ObjHeader      Content-Encoding: gzip
-   ObjHeader      Content-Length: 3684
-   ObjHeader      ETag: "58069548-24f6"
-   ObjHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
-   ObjHeader      X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   ObjHeader      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   ObjHeader      X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   Fetch_Body     3 length stream
-   Gzip           Gunzip error: -3 (incorrect header check)
-   FetchError     Invalid Gzip data: incorrect header check
-   Gzip           u F - 2 0 0 0 0
-   BackendClose   29 boot.default
-   BereqAcct      472 0 472 649 0 649
-   End
```

Now should I skip gzip of SVG files?  Another thing I dont understand is why varnish is messing with the gzipped file. Isnt it supposed to just cache it and pass it along? Gzip or no gzip? It seems like its trying to decompress it for some reason.

Thanks!

Comment: From the varnish docs: If the server responds with gzip'ed content it will be stored in memory in its compressed form and Accept-Encoding will be added to the Vary header.

https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/compression.html

Comment: varnishd (varnish-4.1.3 revision 5e3b6d2)

Comment: I suspect this can also be a problem with my SVG, if anyone can help me debug I`ll be very grateful. http://s3.fibersals.com.br/logos/logo-fibersals.svg is the problematic SVG file. It was generated using osx Boxy SVG. This file serves just fine http://fibersals.com.br/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg. It was generated using a web based favicon tool.

Answer (score 1):

Your nginx backend return the `Vary` header twice with the same value `Accept-Encoding`. I don't know if this is an issue but that the only strange thing I see in your logs...

I was looking for a chunked transfer issue (chunked transfer, Content Length and reverse proxy do not usually mix up well) but that does not seems to be the case here...